# Conditional subschema inclusion in JSON Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Depending on the property `type` I would like to include a subschema so I wrote:

```
"allOf": [
    {
        "if": {
            "properties": { "type": { "const": "foobar" }}
        },
        "then": {
            "$ref": "foobar.schema.json"
        }
    }, ...
]
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. However, if I do the following, I successfully get the `foobar` definitions:

```
"allOf": [
    {
        "$ref": "foobar.schema.json"
    }, ...
]
```

It seems json-schema doesn't support conditional sub-schema inclusion or I don't know how to use it.

Any clues?

My payload is:

```
{
  "type": "foobar",
  "foobarProperty": 42
}
```

Here the same issue with a monolithic schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "definitions": {
      "foo": {
        "lines": {
            "$id": "#/lines",
            "type": "integer",
            "default": 1,
        },        
      }
    },
    "allOf": [
        {
            "if": {
                "properties": { "type": { "const": "foo" }}
            },
            "then": {
                "allOf" : [
                    {"$ref": "#/definitions/foo"}
                ]
            }
        },
    ],
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "$id": "#/properties/type",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["foo", "bar"],
            "default": "foo"
        },

    }
}
```